# How can I unit test a network request using a local json file?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, asynchronous, networking

I'm trying to figure out the best way to unit test a network request. My initial thought was to create a local file with the JSON response for testing purposes but that doesn't seem to be working. See my code below.

I wanna test that I can get a non-nil array back from the completion handler in the function below.

```
class APIClient {
    let downloader = JSONDownloader() // just a class that creates a new data task

    // what I want to test
    func getArticles(from url: URL?, completion: @escaping([Article]?, Error?) -> ()) {
        guard let url = url else { return }

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = downloader.createTask(with: request) { json, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                // parse JSON
                ...

                completion(articles, nil)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I tried testing as shown below to no avail.

```
func testArticleResponseIsNotNil() {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: APIClientTests.self)
    guard let path = Bundle.path(forResource: "response-articles", ofType: "json", inDirectory: bundle.bundlePath) else {
        XCTFail("Missing file: response-articles.json")
        return
    }

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    var articles: [Article]?

    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Articles")
    let client = APIClient()
    client.getArticles(from: url) { response, error in
        articles = response
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5)
    XCTAssertNotNil(articles)
}
```

Any ideas on how exactly I should test this function?

**Edit:** This is the JSONDownloader class.

```
class JSONDownloader {

    let session: URLSession

    init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration) {
        self.session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(configuration: .default)
    }

    typealias JSON = [String: AnyObject]

    func createTask(with request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping(JSON?, Error?) -> ()) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }

            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? JSON
                        completion(json, nil)
                    } catch { completion(nil, error) }
                } else { completion(nil, error) }
            } else { completion(nil, error) }
        }

        return task
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try with URLSession?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav url session in the test case?